# Bamboo - xcode build and creating/modifying keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, bamboo

Our company uses Bamboo to do automated builds for all our projects and this is the first time that we're attempting to do an iOS build.

In the iOS project (app was built using using Ionic + Cordova), we have an iOS build script written using Gulp which begins the build process by creating a keychain and importing the .p12 file into the keychain.  Unfortunately, this step fails and later causes the xcodebuild command to throw an error about Public/Private key pairs not being found for a Provisioning Profile:

```
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    [18:22:07] Finished 'ionic-build-ios' after 7.98 s
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    [18:22:07] Starting 'clean-ipa'...
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    [18:22:07] Finished 'clean-ipa' after 1.66 ms
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    [18:22:07] Starting 'build-ipa'...
error   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    create-keychain "-p" "bhabani" "TriNetMobileNextGen.keychain"
error   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    unlock-keychain "-p" "bhabani" "TriNetMobileNextGen.keychain"
error   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    list-keychains "-s" "/Users/bamboo/Library/Keychains/TriNetMobileNextGen.keychain"
error   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    import "signing/debug/ios/TriNetMobileNextGen.p12" "-k" "/Users/bamboo/Library/Keychains/TriNetMobileNextGen.keychain" "-P" "bhabani" "-A" "/usr/bin/codesign"
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    2 identities imported.
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    User defaults from command line:
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07        IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/APD-MOB2-JOB1/platforms/ios/build/TriNet.xcarchive
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    Build settings from command line:
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution: TriNet Group, Inc.
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07        ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07        PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 17664eed-3044-49fc-9ad1-141b520f4da9
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:07    
build   16-Oct-2015 21:22:08    === CLEAN TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
```

Creating, unlocking, listing, and importing keychains all throw an error.

What's interesting is, when I SSH into the bamboo server and manually run the build script command (gulp build-ios), everything works perfectly and an .ipa file is generated.

Here's what I've tried:

- Added a step in the build script to make change the permissions on keychain file to a+rwx
- Changed the permissions of the ~/Library/Keychains folder to a+rwx

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You might need `security unlock-keychain` in there as well.  In our automated builds we just include the keychain, with a simple password, and use that during the code signing.   I don't see the need to create a temporary keychain every time.

Comment: It is being unlocked after the create-keychain command.  For your automated builds, don't you need to install the keychain using list-keychains?  That step fails for me.

Comment: Looks like everything broke again.  So lame that Atlassian doesn't have an XCode plugin for this.